# File and directory permissions

Tags: htaccess, security, directory, permissions

I installed latest WordPress 3.5 in my CentOS server. When I tried accessing `http://example.com/wp-includes/`, I received a listing of the directory: (**Index of wp-includes**).

I added the following code at the top of `.htaccess` file, and it fixed the issue:

```
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
```

### My problem

When I try accessing PHP files in `wp-includes` and `wp-content` using a web-browser (for example: `http://example.com/wp-includes/class-smtp.php`), it shows a blank screen. I think it should show "Permission denied" or something like this. Am I correct?

How can I achieve this? I'm concerned if my website is vulnerable to attacks. I am already aware of the [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) article.

Here are my directory and file permissions:

- `wp-admin`: 755
- `wp-content`: 755
- `wp-includes`: 755
- Files have permission 644

Comment: Server response has nothing to do with security, what can you do with a blank screen and only read access, nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP files in the `wp-includes` directory will do nothing when accessed directly. They are designed to be `include()`'d in an existing PHP script, such as on the front-end or in the dashboard.

Your `Options -Indexes` entry in the `.htaccess` file simply prevents a list of the files in a directory when no `index.php` is present. It's good practice to use this on a live server. I'm not entirely sure what the second line does; you should most likely remove it.

If you're especially concerned about people attacking your server, you can prevent access to the `wp-includes` directory **completely**. To do this, create a `.htaccess` file *inside* the `wp-includes` folder with the following content:

```
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect your WordPress installation, one thing that I always do when I install WordPress is to protect my wp-admin folder (your login page). What I do is I create .htaccess file in wp-admin and allow only certain IPs to access this folder.
I think there's some info on WordPress login page here:  [htaccess redirect](http://www.htaccessredirect.info/)

Also who is your host? Did you set this server up yourself? You should not be seing your index of wp-includes after you install WordPress. It has never happened to me before. :/

Comment: The login page (`wp-login.php`) isn't part of `wp-admin`

Comment: Yes you are correct. I should have explained this a little better. You can still access your login page by going to domain.com/wp-login.php however, if you do allow only certain IPs to access the wp-admin folder, the ones that are not on the list will get a 403 , permission denied error.